# Passive Constructions

Tags: english, passive

No-one else but me has yet called those passive constructions yet, but I have because I was really not satisfied about the fact that I couldn't differentiate them from one another anyhow.

Do you think I did the right thing?

Here are examples of all the constructions and their differences:

1. Passive I: the usual passive construction; the most important thing in it is the action done.

Examples:

• The house has been built.

• The barbed wires were bended in at night (as the past participle of  *bend*,  *bended* is correct instead of *bent*
as well).

2. Passive II: the most important thing here is the thing received by the subject; not all verbs can be used in it.

Examples:

• I've been brought some fruit by Dad.

• I was knit a pretty-looking sweater.

3. Passive III: here, both the thing and the receiver are important; it's like Passive II, yet all (transitive, indeed) verbs are capable of being used in this passive structure.

Examples:

• A new English topic was explained to me at school.

• The roch found by me at the beach was given to my friend.

Comment: The past participle _bended_ is not really correct, no – it’s highly archaic and only used in the set phrase _on bended knee_. Barbed wire is also generally used as a mass noun, unless you’re talking specifically about multiple, individual pieces of barbed wires. At any rate, ‘the barbed wire was bent in at night’ is a very odd sentence.

Comment: Also, I don’t understand your first sentence – all your examples are very clearly passive constructions, and no one would say that they’re not.

Comment: verb: bend, bent, bend except for things like on bended knee.

Answer (score 2):

A [ditransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb) verb is a verb with two objects, which are a Theme and a Goal. For example, in *Alex gave Andy the book*, *Andy* is the Goal and *the book* is the Theme. In English, [such verbs have two passives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb#Passive_voice):

- With the Theme as the subject: *The book was given to Andy by Alex.*
- With the Goal as the subject: *Andy was given the book by Alex.*

Passive II is a passive of a ditransitive verb with the Goal as the subject:

- *I've been brought some fruit by Dad* from *Dad brought me some fruit*.

Passive III is a passive of a ditransitive verb with the Theme as the subject:

- *A new topic was explained to me* from *(Someone) explained me a new topic*.

Ditransitive verbs can be rephrased as transitive verbs with an indirect object. From *Alex gave Andy the book* we then get *Alex gave the book to Andy*. Passive III can also be seen as a regular passive of such a regular transitive sentence. This explains why Passive III can occur with more verbs than Passive II. Some verbs, like *move*, can take an indirect object with *to* but cannot be used ditransitively. Thus we do have *Alex moved the book to the other shelf* but not **Alex moved the other shelf the book*. Therefore, *move* can appear in Passive III (*The book was moved to the other shelf*) but not Passive II (**The other shelf was moved the book*).

Passive I is a regular passive of a monotransitive verb.

You make a distinction based on what is important (action, thing received, thing and recipient). Indeed, although passivization is a syntactic operation, it serves a semantic-pragmatic goal: to foreground the active object (Patient, Theme, Goal) and background the active subject (Agent). With ditransitives, you have a choice and either the Theme or the Goal can be foregrounded.

Comment: Note that _knit_ is not a ditransitive verb. Like _dig_ or _fix_. If you get a "ditransitive passive" with these verbs (or many others), they unpack as benefactives, not datives: _dig him a clam, knit him a sweater,_ and _fix him a meal_ mean (r-ly) _dig a clam **for** him, knit a sweater **for** him, fix a meal **for** him_. [Benefactives can undergo dative alternation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/15299) iff the benefactee comes to possess the direct object because of the verb action. So *_fix him the car_ does not transfer ownership.

Comment: So, do you like the passive ordering I have personally come up with?

Comment: @jlawler thanks!

Comment: @user41064 it’s a good observation that you made that there are different patterns. Whether the distinction is useful will depend on your goal, of course, and I don’t know what that is. But it is well observed in any case.

Comment: There's actually two rules (constructions, transformations, alternations, whatever) involved here: [Passive and Dative](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/169710/15299). Dative exchanges the DO and IO, optionally (with some idiosyncratic pronoun and preposition details), and Passive  optionally promotes the DO to Subject. After Dative, the semantic receiver is the new DO, and Passive will apply to it. If Dative doesn't apply, the semantic trajector is the DO, and Passive will apply to **it**.

Comment: @jlawler yeah, but if you assume the ditransitive structure as the base in the case that it’s needed, there is only one.

Comment: @Keelan But then you hafta provide motivation for the ditransitive structure. Without that, it's just handwaving, and either way it's gonna be complex. Reducing the number of rules used in a derivation is a very abstract motive.